# How to access a table using a variable name in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have multiple tables in my database named teacher1, teacher2.... I am trying to access them using a variable `$id.`

I have written down the following code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table.$id";
```

How could i access those different tables using a variable.

Comment: Does `$id` contain the table name?  Or perhaps the number of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear from the question text whether your `$id` variable contains the full table name, or some kind of number.

However, in either case you have to make a slight tweak to your `$query` variable.

If `$id` contains the *full name of the table* (i.e. `teacher1`):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $id;
```

If `$id` contains *a number used to identify which teacher table it is* (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teacher" . $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use parameters!

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query = "SELECT t.* FROM table t where t.id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

$stmt->execute();
```

Don't munge query strings with parameter values!  This introduces SQL injection risk, can introduce syntax errors that are hard to debug, and can degrade performance.

Comment: This is a question about dynamic SQL involving a changeable table name, nothing to do with `WHERE` clauses. Ref the question: _How could i access those different **tables** using a variable_